# Singularity of a surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces, implicit-function-theorem

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Grad}{grad}$I know a surface is singular at a point when gradient vanishes at that point.
If $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ then $\Grad f = (2x, 2y)$ and $\Grad f(0,0) = (0,0)$.
Does this mean $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ is singular at $(0,0)$? I don't see a cusp at this point and surface $f(x,y)$ seems to me having a tangent at $(0,0)$ which is the $x$-$y$ plane. Should I consider $\Grad f$ as normal to the tangent of the level curve at $(0,0)$ and as level curve $x^2 + y^2 = 0$ is indeed not a curve but only a point then the normal is not defined at this point? Thank you in advance

Comment: The paraboloid $z = x^2 + y^2$ is the zero set of the function $F(x, y, z) := x^2 + y^2 - z$, and $\nabla F$ vanishes nowhere, so the paraboloid is nonsingular. On the other hand, the gradient of $G(x, y, z) = x^2 + y^2 - z^2$ vanishes at the origin, so the cone $G(x, y, z) = 0$ has a singularity there.

Comment: Where have you  see the definition '' a surface is singular at a point when gradient vanishes at that point''?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know a surface is singular at a point when gradient vanishes at that point.

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}\newcommand{\grad}{\nabla}$To clarify: If $F:U \to \Reals$ is a real-valued function on some non-empty open subset $U$ of $\Reals^{3}$, and if $\grad F(p) \neq 0$ at some point $p$ of $U$, the implicit function theorem guarantees that the level set of $F$ through $p$ is a regular surface in *some neighborhood* of $p$.

There are at least two snags with your proposed example:

1. Your surface is expressed as a *graph*, not as a *level surface*. If you express the defining equation $z = f(x, y)$ in "level set form"
   $$
   0 = F(x, y, z) := z - f(x, y),
   $$
   you find that $\grad F = (-f_{x}, -f_{y}, 1) \neq (0, 0, 0)$.
2. The converse of the implicit function theorem is not true. The level surface
   $$
   0 = F(x, y, z) = z^{3}
   $$
   is the image of a regular surface, but $\grad F \equiv 0$ *everywhere* on the level surface.

Comment: @Hwang; So I have misunderstood the condition of being a singular point. I should have considered the point where grad of the 0 level set vanishes, right?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you mean by "grad of the $0$ level set". A _function_ has a gradient; a level is a _set_. But again, even if $\grad F$ vanishes at some point $p$ of a level set, that does not by itself show the level set is singular at $p$.